# How do I put two linear-gradients on the left and right border?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm looking to create a yellow div with wide left and right borders. Towards the outside edges of the div, the left and right borders taper in colour down to white to simulate transparency.

So far I've been able to construct the div, but not the gradient:

```css
.fade {
  margin: 2em 2em; padding-top: 2em; padding-bottom: 2em;
  background: rgb(242,242,194);

  border-right: 3em black solid;
  border-left: 3em black solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 0%, rgb(242, 242, 194) 100%);
{
```

```html
<div class="fade">Text</div>
```

What happens can be seen above: the linear gradient correctly overrides the black to make a yellow border, but there's no fade to white that I'm looking for. There's no gradient at all, in fact.

The final product should look like this:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't familiar with gradients and you don't want to mess with them you should use Colorzilla gradient tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

```css
    .fade {
      margin: 2em 2em; padding-top: 2em; padding-bottom: 2em;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, white 0%, rgb(242, 242, 194) 5%, rgb(242, 242, 194) 95%, white 100%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="fade">Text</div>
```

Maybe something like this can be useful?

I will explain what I did.

I deleted every attribute that contains `border` and I only used `background`.

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, white 0%, rgb(242, 242, 194) 5%, rgb(242, 242, 194) 95%, white 100%);
```

This gradient has 4 steps:

- The first step tells that the gradient has to start in white.
- The second step (5% of the width of the element) tells that the gradient follows yellow.
- Until third step (95% of the width of the element).
- Then, in fourth step it ends with white again.

**Note** that this percentages are for the width because you have rotated the gradient 90 degrees, with 0 or 360 you will affect the height part of the gradient.

A last detail, you will need some padding inside the div to make the text looks exactly like your photo.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, white 0%, rgb(242, 242, 194) 8%, rgb(242, 242, 194) 92%, white 100%);
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 30px;
}
p {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div><p>Text</p></div>
```